# Authorize works but Roles don't work in dotnet core with JWT

Tags: .net-core, jwt

I use JWT like below , when just use **Authorize** it works properly, but when want to use **Role** it doesn't work

**Startup:**

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            //...
            AddOAuthProviders(services);
            //...
        }

        public IServiceCollection AddOAuthProviders(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAuthentication(x =>
            {
                x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                {
                    OnTokenValidated = context =>
                    {
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },
                };
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.SaveToken = true;
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Security.secretKey)),
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false
                };
            });

            return services;
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IUnitOfWork uow)
        {
            //....
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            //...
        }
```

**In Authenticate method :**

```
//...
var claims = new List<Claim>
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserId.ToString()),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, userRoles),//Read,Write
                };
//...
```

**Controllers :**

```
[HttpPost]
        [Authorize(Roles = "Write")]
        public ActionResult Insert ...
```

Comment: do you mean `userRoles` has the value of "Read,Write" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are adding multiple roles in a single claim by doing this:

```
new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, userRoles)
```

If you have multiple roles, each needs to be a separate claim. Like this:

```
new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Read")
new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Write")
```

If you are getting your roles in a comma-separated string `userRoles`, you could use some Linq magic to add the roles:

```
claims.AddRange(userRoles.Split(',').Select(r => new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, r)));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I just figured out how solved an issue that worked for me because I had a similar problem when using JWT.

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer", Roles = "Manager")]
```

When I use 'Roles' by itself like this:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Manager")]
```

it does not work.

But, when I use it with

```
'Authentication Schemes = "Bearer'
```

, it works fine. I don't understand why. If someone can explain, that would be awesome!

I think it may have something to do with the Request coming to the server.